# I can't install locales due to varnish cache

Tags: debian, varnish, localization

We're having locale issues on a server, but if I am to install `locales` it will uninstall `varnish`.

It's Debian 8 and a test system, so nothing in production will be affected.

Is there a way to install `locales` without uninstalling `varnish`, or are there alternative ways to set locales?

Comment: I'd use Debian's locales, and a varnish downloaded and compiled from varnish-cache.org.  Where did you get your varnish version?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille I don't know exactly, as I am not the guy who setup the server, but I wouldn't be surprised if it were from either varnish repos or debian repos like all the other servers.

Comment: Odd to have a conflict with locales.  Make sure your Varnish is kept up to date, since it's often very close to the internet, you wouldn't want to be running with a known vulnerability.  Are you aware that LTS for Debian Jessie ended in june 2020?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille I am fully aware of the LTS support and I have urged for upgrades before; customer just doesn't prioritise it. It's "just" a test environment, so I could save the configuration of varnish and install locales; just wanted to see if I could avoid that.

Comment: If your configuration is compatible with the new version of Varnish that you would be installing. Easy to test on a separate install.